# Android 7 - How to save new contacts to the phone

Tags: google-account, 7.1-nougat, google-contacts

I have an Android 7.1.1 phone. Before I linked it to a Google account, new contacts would be saved to the phone itself (I think SIM card was also an option).

Now That I've added my Google account, I no longer see "Phone" as a save option. I am forced to save contacts to my Google account (see screenshot).

[image: creating a new contact - save options]

Before I added the Google account, the Contact app setting below was unset. Now I cannot deselect Google.

[image: contact app setting - default account]

Is it possible to have contact saved to the phone only? I don't want my contacts automatically linked to my Google account.

Comment: Third party so [like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keesadens.SIMcardToolManager) may help?

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks for the suggestion. I'd like to keep using the default Contacts if possible, since other apps depend on it.